# How to convert a URL to lowercase while serving a page with a query string?

Tags: regex, linux, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to forward a URL from `example.com/dir/textstring-VARIABLE.html` to `example.com/dir/textstring-variable.html`, while serving the page `example.com/dir/textstring.html?var=variable`.

The code I use to serve the page with the query string is:

`#RewriteRule ^textstring-([a-zA-Z]+)-?([a-zA-Z]*)-?([a-zA-Z]*)-?\(*([a-zA-Z]*)\)*.html?$ /dir/textstring.html?var=$1\%20$2\%20$3\%20$4`

I also understand there are [ways to convert to lowercase](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18670/how-to-redirect-convert-any-url-to-lowercase), however, I can't seem to figure out how to do both together.

Comment: Do you control both pages?  In general, URLs are case-sensitive and you cannot change the case of an arbitrary URL without breaking it.

Comment: (That rule does a lot more than what you've stated in the example?) Is that the complete "working" rule? How are you reading the URL parameter? "I can't seem to figure out how to do both together" - From an SEO perspective, you probably shouldn't as it potentially causes a duplicate content issue.

Comment: You can't do both things together in one single action, if you want the URL shown on the client to actually change - that requires a redirect first, and then you can rewrite the new request made for the lowercased URL.

Comment: I do control both pages. I'm not trying to end up with 2 URLs, I only want the lowercase one, but the uppercase URL got into the Google index and I want to forward it  to the lowercase URL. I don't need to do them in  a single statement, just in one .htaccess file

Comment: Then do _exactly_ as stated in [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/133257/1243) to [the question on Webmasters SE that you've already linked to](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18670/how-to-redirect-convert-any-url-to-lowercase) (the other answers to that question are out of date). This redirect rule should obviously go _before_ your rewrite above. (And join the Webmasters SE community - that is arguably a better place to ask these types of questions anyway.)

Comment: If I do as stated, I end up with a lowercase, but like this:
example.com/dir/textstring.html?var=variable 
How do I get it back to the SEO friendly URL?